# Jenkins - Copy parameters from prior build to current build

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins

How to copy values supplied to a Jenkins job parameters from prior build to current one? Is there a plug-in that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values in a log file and archive it in the build. In the current build you just copy the artifacts from the last build and inject the log file. Check out https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin